# New Apple nfc door opener as seen on iPhone 12 keynote video?

Tags: iphone, ios, nfc

[image]

Anyone has info about this technology? Looks like we can scan nfc or emulate keys on the embarked nfc chip? or is it only for apple internal use?

Answer (score 1):

NFC detection is available to app developers on iPhone for some years since iOS 11.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc

I use it for hardware authorization with yubikeys and 1Password app.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/1password-password-manager/id568903335
- https://www.yubico.com/us/store

Apple hardware can scan for NFC and then take whatever action the developers code up for the apps.

Comment: thank you for you answer but so far you get a notification you have to click to open the app that can then trigger a remote order to open the door right? you can't juste swipe your phone in front of the nfc without having to tap your screen right?

Comment: We will have to examine the specific app you mention. I have no information on that. I tried to answer from what is documented and known and shipping.